# My Highchart is displaying (drawing) my data sporadically, instead of in a clean line left to right

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take an 2D array [timestamp, count] and display it on a highchart for 90 days from left to right. The problem I'm having is the chart seems to be displaying this just completely sporadically. This is working with a smaller data set but when I introduce it to prod data it does this.

Verified timestamps are correct.
Verified that I'm passing my Array correctly in the Highchart initializer.

```
// Hichchart Initializer
var getAcbsOverLastNinetyDays = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ActualCashBalanceOverNinetyDays",
            success: function (data) {
                var processedAcbsArray = processAcbs(data.acbs);
                // Create Highchart using ProcessedAcbsArray
                setTimeout(function () {
                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                            chart: {
                                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                                plotShadow: false,
                                renderTo: "acb-chart",
                                type: "line",
                                zoomType: "x"
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            exporting: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            legend: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                type: "datetime",
                                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                    month: "%b '%y"
                                },
                                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    formatter: function() {
                                        return this.value / 1000000 + " Million";
                                    }
                                },
                                opposite: true
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                series: {
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: false,
                                        y: 0
                                    }
                                },
                                line: {
                                    marker: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        symbol: "circle",
                                        radius: 4,
                                        states: {
                                            hover: {
                                                enabled: true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    var date = new Date(this.x);
                                    return getDayOfTheWeek(date.getDay()) + ", " + getMonth(date.getMonth()) + " " + date.getDate() + "<br/>Count: " + this.y ;
                                },
                                shared: true
                            },
                            series: [
                                {
                                    name: "ACB Metric",
                                    type: "line",
                                    color: "#449d44",
                                    data: processedAcbsArray
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    }

// Exact Array I'm passing (processedAcbsArray):
0: (2) [1561852800000, 1178820]
1: (2) [1562544000000, 1175922]
2: (2) [1566000000000, 1197105]
3: (2) [1561420800000, 1174743]
4: (2) [1564876800000, 1188984]
5: (2) [1564963200000, 1188888]
6: (2) [1566259200000, 1197595]
7: (2) [1561593600000, 1176852]
8: (2) [1561766400000, 1178268]
9: (2) [1563321600000, 1181110]
10: (2) [1563753600000, 1183704]
11: (2) [1564617600000, 1188362]
12: (2) [1565395200000, 1194474]
13: (2) [1568764800000, 1214243]
14: (2) [1561161600000, 1173741]
15: (2) [1564444800000, 1186430]
16: (2) [1566691200000, 1200370]
17: (2) [1567468800000, 1203268]
18: (2) [1561248000000, 1174900]
19: (2) [1562803200000, 1177216]
20: (2) [1564099200000, 1185568]
21: (2) [1566432000000, 1198520]
22: (2) [1567036800000, 1201729]
23: (2) [1568678400000, 1213346]
24: (2) [1562284800000, 1176398]
25: (2) [1562371200000, 1176135]
26: (2) [1563148800000, 1180086]
27: (2) [1565913600000, 1196303]
28: (2) [1566950400000, 1200921]
29: (2) [1567382400000, 1203109]
30: (2) [1568073600000, 1208852]
31: (2) [1561680000000, 1177802]
32: (2) [1566604800000, 1199785]
33: (2) [1566777600000, 1200286]
34: (2) [1567555200000, 1203566]
35: (2) [1568160000000, 1209541]
36: (2) [1568332800000, 1210798]
37: (2) [1561507200000, 1175947]
38: (2) [1561939200000, 1178728]
39: (2) [1562112000000, 1179895]
40: (2) [1562976000000, 1179537]
41: (2) [1563580800000, 1182981]
42: (2) [1565136000000, 1192402]
43: (2) [1566518400000, 1199273]
44: (2) [1567209600000, 1202617]
45: (2) [1567728000000, 1207123]
46: (2) [1568592000000, 1213318]
47: (2) [1563235200000, 1180230]
48: (2) [1565222400000, 1193112]
49: (2) [1565308800000, 1194054]
50: (2) [1566086400000, 1197578]
51: (2) [1562025600000, 1178785]
52: (2) [1565049600000, 1188992]
53: (2) [1567900800000, 1209312]
54: (2) [1568419200000, 1211391]
55: (2) [1565568000000, 1194470]
56: (2) [1566345600000, 1198096]
57: (2) [1567123200000, 1202149]
58: (2) [1567814400000, 1208609]
59: (2) [1568505600000, 1213334]
60: (2) [1561075200000, 1172732]
61: (2) [1563840000000, 1183869]
62: (2) [1564531200000, 1187235]
63: (2) [1564704000000, 1189377]
64: (2) [1564790400000, 1187994]
65: (2) [1567641600000, 1205821]
66: (2) [1563408000000, 1181493]
67: (2) [1564185600000, 1185882]
68: (2) [1564358400000, 1186309]
69: (2) [1565740800000, 1194962]
70: (2) [1567296000000, 1203209]
71: (2) [1561334400000, 1174712]
72: (2) [1562716800000, 1176777]
73: (2) [1563494400000, 1182332]
74: (2) [1564272000000, 1186470]
75: (2) [1565654400000, 1194501]
76: (2) [1562198400000, 1174925]
77: (2) [1562630400000, 1176103]
78: (2) [1562889600000, 1178945]
79: (2) [1563667200000, 1183807]
80: (2) [1565827200000, 1195435]
81: (2) [1567987200000, 1209091]
82: (2) [1565481600000, 1194600]
83: (2) [1566172800000, 1197440]
84: (2) [1566864000000, 1200207]
85: (2) [1562457600000, 1176297]
86: (2) [1563062400000, 1180220]
87: (2) [1563926400000, 1184434]
88: (2) [1564012800000, 1184820]
89: (2) [1568246400000, 1210157]
length: 90
__proto__: Array(0)
```

My expected results is that these points will display the count for each day for the past 90 days from left to right.

Actual, its displaying All over the place, best I can describe is it looks like a total mess of cats cradle. I'll see if I can't provide a screenshot.

This is my Actual once I introduce to prod, with the array provided Above.
[image: This is my actual from prod using the array provided Above]

Test Data, same initializer, only difference is smaller count value at least that i can tell.
[image: This is my test data and it works great, only difference is smaller count. The codes identical]

```
//Here's the test Data array:
0: (2) [1561075200000, 144]
1: (2) [1561161600000, 144]
2: (2) [1561248000000, 144]
3: (2) [1561334400000, 144]
4: (2) [1561420800000, 144]
5: (2) [1561507200000, 144]
6: (2) [1561593600000, 144]
7: (2) [1561680000000, 154]
8: (2) [1561766400000, 154]
9: (2) [1561852800000, 155]
10: (2) [1561939200000, 155]
11: (2) [1562025600000, 155]
12: (2) [1562112000000, 155]
13: (2) [1562198400000, 155]
14: (2) [1562284800000, 155]
15: (2) [1562371200000, 155]
16: (2) [1562457600000, 155]
17: (2) [1562544000000, 155]
18: (2) [1562630400000, 155]
19: (2) [1562716800000, 155]
20: (2) [1562803200000, 155]
21: (2) [1562889600000, 155]
22: (2) [1562976000000, 155]
23: (2) [1563062400000, 155]
24: (2) [1563321600000, 155]
25: (2) [1563408000000, 155]
26: (2) [1563494400000, 155]
27: (2) [1563580800000, 155]
28: (2) [1563667200000, 155]
29: (2) [1563753600000, 155]
30: (2) [1563840000000, 155]
31: (2) [1563926400000, 155]
32: (2) [1564012800000, 155]
33: (2) [1564099200000, 155]
34: (2) [1564185600000, 155]
35: (2) [1564272000000, 155]
36: (2) [1564358400000, 155]
37: (2) [1564444800000, 155]
38: (2) [1564531200000, 156]
39: (2) [1564617600000, 156]
40: (2) [1564704000000, 156]
41: (2) [1564790400000, 156]
42: (2) [1564876800000, 156]
43: (2) [1564963200000, 156]
44: (2) [1565049600000, 156]
45: (2) [1565136000000, 156]
46: (2) [1565222400000, 156]
47: (2) [1565308800000, 156]
48: (2) [1565395200000, 156]
49: (2) [1565481600000, 156]
50: (2) [1565568000000, 156]
51: (2) [1565654400000, 156]
52: (2) [1565740800000, 156]
53: (2) [1565827200000, 156]
54: (2) [1565913600000, 156]
55: (2) [1566000000000, 156]
56: (2) [1566086400000, 156]
57: (2) [1566172800000, 156]
58: (2) [1566259200000, 157]
59: (2) [1566345600000, 157]
60: (2) [1566432000000, 157]
61: (2) [1566518400000, 157]
62: (2) [1566604800000, 157]
63: (2) [1566777600000, 314]
64: (2) [1566864000000, 314]
65: (2) [1566950400000, 157]
66: (2) [1567036800000, 158]
67: (2) [1567555200000, 159]
68: (2) [1567641600000, 159]
69: (2) [1567728000000, 159]
70: (2) [1567814400000, 158]
71: (2) [1567900800000, 158]
72: (2) [1567987200000, 158]
73: (2) [1568073600000, 158]
74: (2) [1568160000000, 159]
75: (2) [1568246400000, 160]
76: (2) [1568332800000, 159]
77: (2) [1568419200000, 159]
78: (2) [1568505600000, 159]
79: (2) [1568592000000, 159]
80: (2) [1568678400000, 159]
81: (2) [1568764800000, 159]
length: 82
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: what is the reason of setTimeout

Comment: @brk, this is just an inhouse thing we use if something is taking too long, this should have no baring on the chart. The page loads within a second.

Comment: @brk, I also just tested this by removing the Timeout function. It had no affect. Till crazy drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Well, this is quite embarrassing but once I provided the arrays in the question. I noticed the timestamps..............

Well, they are not in order...

The chart plots points sequentially based on the order of my array. So I simply sorted the array by time stamp and voila ... Comes out correctly:

```
processedJson = processedJson.sort(function(timeStamp, count) {
            if (timeStamp[0] === count[0]) {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return (timeStamp[0] < count[0]) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For line chart you need all the data in a single array. Seem you have multiple array so it is plotting multiple line. In this example I have used `flat` to convert array of arrays to single array

```js
let data = [
  [1561075200000, 144],
  [1561161600000, 144],
  [1561248000000, 144],
  [1561334400000, 144],
  [1561420800000, 144],
  [1561507200000, 144],
  [1561593600000, 144],
  [1561680000000, 154],
  [1561766400000, 154],
  [1561852800000, 155],
  [1561939200000, 155],
  [1562025600000, 155],
  [1562112000000, 155],
  [1562198400000, 155],
  [1562284800000, 155],
  [1562371200000, 155],
  [1562457600000, 155],
  [1562544000000, 155],
  [1562630400000, 155],
  [1562716800000, 155],
  [1562803200000, 155],
  [1562889600000, 155],
  [1562976000000, 155],
  [1563062400000, 155],
  [1563321600000, 155],
  [1563408000000, 155],
  [1563494400000, 155],
  [1563580800000, 155],
  [1563667200000, 155],
  [1563753600000, 155],
  [1563840000000, 155],
  [1563926400000, 155],
  [1564012800000, 155],
  [1564099200000, 155],
  [1564185600000, 155],
  [1564272000000, 155],
  [1564358400000, 155],
  [1564444800000, 155],
  [1564531200000, 156],
  [1564617600000, 156],
  [1564704000000, 156],
  [1564790400000, 156],
  [1564876800000, 156],
  [1564963200000, 156],
  [1565049600000, 156],
  [1565136000000, 156],
  [1565222400000, 156],
  [1565308800000, 156],
  [1565395200000, 156],
  [1565481600000, 156],
  [1565568000000, 156],
  [1565654400000, 156],
  [1565740800000, 156],
  [1565827200000, 156],
  [1565913600000, 156],
  [1566000000000, 156],
  [1566086400000, 156],
  [1566172800000, 156],
  [1566259200000, 157],
  [1566345600000, 157],
  [1566432000000, 157],
  [1566518400000, 157],
  [1566604800000, 157],
  [1566777600000, 314],
  [1566864000000, 314],
  [1566950400000, 157],
  [1567036800000, 158],
  [1567555200000, 159],
  [1567641600000, 159],
  [1567728000000, 159],
  [1567814400000, 158],
  [1567900800000, 158],
  [1567987200000, 158],
  [1568073600000, 158],
  [1568160000000, 159],
  [1568246400000, 160],
  [1568332800000, 159],
  [1568419200000, 159],
  [1568505600000, 159],
  [1568592000000, 159],
  [1568678400000, 159],
  [1568764800000, 159]
]

let processedAcbsArray = data.flat();

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,
    renderTo: "acb-chart",
    type: "line",
    zoomType: "x"
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      month: "%b '%y"
    },
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      enabled: false
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value / 1000000 + " Million";
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        y: 0
      }
    },
    line: {
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        symbol: "circle",
        radius: 4,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var date = new Date(this.x);
      return getDayOfTheWeek(date.getDay()) + ", " + getMonth(date.getMonth()) + " " + date.getDate() + "<br/>Count: " + this.y;
    },
    shared: true
  },
  series: [{
    name: "ACB Metric",
    type: "line",
    color: "#449d44",
    data: processedAcbsArray
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="acb-chart"></div>
```

Comment: Error - Uncaught Reference: getDayOfTheWeek is not defined

Comment: This is actually a correct observation that is should be a single array, but i'm most definitely not sending multiple arrays, the manual format in which you placed the array in your example is how the array is being provided. I've found the solution, and will answer the question in a moment.